# Is there still a performance benefit in affinity groups inside regional virtual networks?

Tags: networking, azure, azure-affinity-group

Now there's the new [Azure Regional Virtual Networks feature](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/regional-virtual-networks/) that spans a region, is there a performance benefit of using affinity groups? In the FAQ part of the linked blog post there reads

> **Do I incur any performance degradation for services running inside a Regional Virtual Network?**
>
> Virtual network is only a logical boundary, it does not dictate where
>   the deployments in the VNet actually go to. If for some reason, you
>   need services to be in the same Affinity group, you can still do that
>   inside a regional virtual network. During deployment you will have to
>   specify the Affinity group to which the hosted service should be bound
>   to. The only restriction would be, that the Affinity groups should
>   belong to the same region as the Regional Virtual network.
>
> If you do not bind your hosted service to an Affinity group, and
>   deploy services directly to the Regional Virtual Network, your
>   deployments will be placed in a scale unit inside the region the
>   Virtual Network is bound to.

I get a feeling the recommendation is not to use affinity groups at all anymore (based on this and some other posts, maybe it's my Azure and/or English comprehension, though), but would the services and data be co-located in the data center then?

<edit: Of course just after writing this I discovered a MSDN article [About Regional VNets and Affinity Groups for Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-migrate-to-regional-vnet/) which states

> Previously, when creating a virtual network (VNet) you were required
>   to associate the VNet with an affinity group, which was in turn,
>   associated with a Region. This requirement has changed. Now VNets are
>   associated directly with a Region (Location) in the Management Portal.
>   This allows you more freedom when creating your VNets. You can still
>   associate your cloud services with affinity groups when appropriate,
>   but you are not required to do so.
>
> The *Region* represents where the Virtual Network overlay will be.
>   Anything you deploy to the virtual network will be physically located
>   in the Region. If you want to further designate that you want your
>   resources in close proximity physically to each other within the same
>   region, you can specify an affinity group for those particular
>   resources. That would mean that not only are those resources in the
>   same physical location, they are very close to each other in the
>   datacenter.

So, I suppose there is a performance benefit to be had when using affinity groups.

**<edit:** The most definitive source for the little performance edge and use cases for affinity groups I can find is to be found at [Convective blog post Affinity Groups in Azure](http://convective.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/affinity-groups-in-azure/).

> An affinity group serves two purposes:
>
> 1. colocation of cloud service and storage account
> 2. host for an affinity group VNET
>
> The second of these is now deprecated. The first is still possible but
>   has not been emphasized as the latency optimization it was prior to
>   the upgrade of the Azure network in 2012. In fact the standard way to
>   deploy a VM in the Azure Portal does not support the simultaneous
>   creation of a cloud service in an affinity group and a regional VNET.
>   This confuses people who try to satisfy the modern best practice of
>   using a regional VNET for deployments and the historic best practice
>   of creating a cloud service in an affinity group.
>
> At this point there seems to be little reason to deploy a cloud
>   service into an affinity group. However, as with other deployment
>   choices it might be wise for people to test this out for their
>   specific workloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also the original question. The most definitive source for the little performance edge and use cases for affinity groups I can find is to be found at [Convective blog post Affinity Groups in Azure](http://convective.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/affinity-groups-in-azure/).

> An affinity group serves two purposes:
>
> 1. colocation of cloud service and storage account
> 2. host for an affinity group VNET
>
> The second of these is now deprecated. The first is still possible but
>   has not been emphasized as the latency optimization it was prior to
>   the upgrade of the Azure network in 2012. In fact the standard way to
>   deploy a VM in the Azure Portal does not support the simultaneous
>   creation of a cloud service in an affinity group and a regional VNET.
>   This confuses people who try to satisfy the modern best practice of
>   using a regional VNET for deployments and the historic best practice
>   of creating a cloud service in an affinity group.
>
> At this point there seems to be little reason to deploy a cloud
>   service into an affinity group. However, as with other deployment
>   choices it might be wise for people to test this out for their
>   specific workloads.

Answer (score 1):

Its never been definitively proven that there is a performance/latency benefit from the use of affinity groups. Reports of such benefits (or lack thereof) have varied widely and are largely anecdotal.